# How to install font from sources

Tags: font

What is the right way to install [font from sources](http://sourceforge.net/projects/terminus-font) on OS X?

Comment: Fonts are not coded. What you are looking for is a way to use or convert BDF on Mac.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t want the "source" package from SourceForge, instead download the TrueType (TTF) fonts optimized for OS X from [this website.](http://misc.nybergh.net/pub/fonts/terminus/ttf_for_osx/) No need to convert BDF files!